# How to inspect outgoing https traffic from OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, https, terminal, fiddler, charles-proxy

I am trying to inspect some outgoing https requests from a command line utility running in the OSX terminal but they don't seem to show up in tools like Charles or Fiddler. Can anyone suggest a tool that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/). It's an open-source project I've been working on. It has a button that opens a terminal window, where every command run in that terminal is automatically intercepted.

This isn't 100% bulletproof (your CLI tool must either correctly follow the standard conventions for proxy configuration, or use one of the languages that the tool can manually redirect) but it should work for 95+% of cases!

If you're interested in how this works so you can do similar things manually: it's basically a *lot* of [environment variables](https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-server/blob/09004bdc321899f6691b11a7d6861a7c5a2d8fbe/src/interceptors/terminal/terminal-env-overrides.ts#L23-L74) to set default configuration, and a few [overrides](https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-server/tree/master/overrides) into your PATH/PYTHONPATH/etc, but all set just for that one intercepted terminal.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was able to use the "--verbose" option on the CLI utility I wanted to investigate which worked.